# Delphi ADO can't find MSSQL 2019 server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, delphi-2010, sql-server-2019-express

I needed to update my old 2008 MSSQL to 2019 Express. (Both accessed locally on the same computer)

This works as far as I can tell since I can see my database in SQL Server Management Studio. So seems to me that is working. (The way I test is I also make sure to have the old server shut down while testing on the new.)

However, my old Delphi 2010 software (which uses some *old* components for *other things* making it hard to upgrade) can not connect to MSSQL2019 through ADO it seems...

To make the example simple... I have my TADOConnection in my IDE. As server to connect to I choose my own computer where MSSQLServerExpress2019 is installed. (Same with 2008) I select "Use Window NT Integrated security" (which I also chose for MSSQL2019Express)

I then try select the database on server... This gives error:

> [DBNETLIB[ConnectionOpen (Connect().]SQL Server does not exist or
> access denied

I am trying to determine... How can I solve this. I am kinda surprised the ADO mechanism stopped working... Maybe there are some settings in my MSSQL2019Express I can set?

The connection string is:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Data Source=mySERVERINSTANCE

**HAVE TRIED**

1. In SQL Server Configuration I have in protocol for MSSQLExpress 2019 enabled TCP/IP (I can see I still have it disabled for my old MSSQL2008)
2. In SQL Server Configuration I have in protocol for MSSQLExpress 2019 enabled Named pipes (I can see I still have it disabled for my old MSSQL2008)
3. In DelphiXE4 I just also tried ADO connection in IDE. Here I have tried "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". Same error.
4. In DelphiXE4 I just also tried ADO connection in IDE. Here I have tried "SQLNCLI11.1" for provider. This gives error comparable error.

Comment: Sorry, but MySQL components to connect to MS SQL Server. It sounds strange

Comment: Where do you see I write that? The same app access MySQL database through some old MySQL databases... and uses ADO for accessing MSSQL database... I do not think that is particular rare that an application accesses multiple database. In hindsight maybe stupid but this is an app I slowly started in 2005 for administrating customers/sales info internally and syncing some info to web when processing sales. Nontheless, I will leave out the mention of MySQL if it confuses... I can see how mentioning it might confuse so thanks for your feedback. Just wanted to explain why I did not try new Delphi :)

Comment: Sorry. Now it is clear

Comment: `my old Delphi 2010 software` it's been 12 years. Protocols change, drivers change. You can't expect using a 12-year old driver to connect to a current database without *some* issues. You aren't using ADO directly either, you're using it through some Delphi components

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree. I just tried XE4 as well. Same problem. I guess I will try using a newer version of Delphi trial. If XE4 could work, I might try work around the problems I have with old components I only have for 2010 :-/

Comment: Or upgrade to something recent. Googling for `MSRDTS` returns nothing relevant. Googling for `Delphi MSRDTS` returns results for `Delphi Murders`. Or for some R packages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can see I have remove another confusing thing. As written, "MSRDTS" is the name of my computer. (One has to select a server to connect to in the ADO connection dialog...) I will remove the mention of that since it confuses...

Comment: I am using ADO from an old Delphi 7 application to connect with mssql 2019, so the problem is not using old drivers. My guess is there is something not correct in your connection string

Comment: @GuidoG which kind of authentication are you using? I am starting to think it may be the Windows NT causing issues. I am adding one more thing to the list of things I have tried...

Comment: Just a note - I also use ADO and Delphi 7 ( ... it's an old project) and I can successfully connect to SQL Server 2017 (not 2019),

Comment: Just to 100% understand. You can connect to 2017, but not tried 2019? Which authentication mode do you use? I am trying to use builtin Windows NT user authentication, but maybe that is causing problems. Can I see connectionstring maybe? (remove sensitive parts)

Comment: Maybe look at this : https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/

Comment: I always use username/password (sql authentication) in stead of windows nt user authentication, but it should also work

Comment: @Tom, yes I'm connecting successfully to SQL Server 2017 instance using old Delphi 7 and TADOConnection. I dont have SQL Server 2019 installed, so I can't make a test. I'm using SQL authentication for this project.

Comment: `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Data Source=mySERVERINSTANCE` this is all I have in my connectionstring

Comment: I don't expect there'd be a serious difference between connecting to SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019 - they both use the same TDS (Tabular Data Stream) version 7.4 protocol that's been in use since SQL Server 2012. The upcoming SQL Server 2022 release would be a different story, however, since it's a major version bump to 8.0 and requires Transport Layer Security (similarly to HTTPS) before it starts exchanging application layer packets.

Comment: So you mentioned turning off SQL Server 2008 while testing SQL Server 2019... are they installed on the same computer? Are you using the Instance Name in your TADOConnection connection string? If so, you need to restart the SQL Browser service on the computer when swapping the instances around - it only looks up the running instance configurations when it starts up so it will likely be presenting incorrect port responses to client inquiries.

Comment: @GuidoG what is the real value of `mySERVERINSTANCE`? SQL Server *Express* is always a named instance called`SQLEXPRESS`. That name must be appended to the machine name or IP, eg `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @GuidoG how are you connecting with SSMS? You have to specify the instance name there as well. You can't connect to `.`, you have to connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Thank you everyone... Switching authentication mode and giving full server instance name Source=.\SQLEXPRESS worked in XE4. That is huge step forward. I will report back with more testing on Delphi 2010 and start turning of things as well to give complete answer. (Kinda weird this was not necessary with old server. My connectionstring there in fact contained completely wrong computer reference...)

Comment: _contained completely wrong computer reference._ Which suggests you (or someone else) did some configuration trickery that no one documented. In turn, that means you have no working DR plan.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Currently I connect with an sql server standard edition, but this delphi 7 program also was used for an sql server express edition, I don't remember the exact connectionstring there. I usually make a `.udl` file and open that, and there I set the properties until it connects, so I can get the necessary fields from there

Comment: @SMor I will blame myself in 2008. (It's only me.) After digging through my old program I did runtime configuration as well which was more appropriate. Generally, I like to clear out visual configuration settings done in IDE to avoid confusing myself later on. Hard to return back 10+ years later to something you forgot everything about :)

Answer (score -1):

I appears using
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
or
Source=MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS
for MSSQLServer 2019

Funny thing in e.g. IDE ADO connection I can connect to my 2008 server just using:
Source=MyComputer

Thank you everyone. It just been so insanely long time since I last looked at this code, so rusty as hell with everything regarding MSSQL and how my setup was done and where my code did things.

Sorry for all the confusion. But thank you so much for your help.

Hopefully maybe this answer could conceivably be help to someone out there.